# Reorder alternate colors

Tags: jquery

I have a table with alternate color rows.

```
$("#contTbl tr:even").addClass("altBgr");
```

Than I have a function that does some transaction and after AJAX post it removed the row.

```
$(".clickMe").click(function() {
        var trID = $(this).closest("tr").attr("id");
        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: { 
                contID: trID
            },
            success: function(data){
                $("#"+trID).remove();
            }
        });
    });
```

The problem that I have is when I remove a row, the color of the other rows becomes out of order... Is there a way to refresh it somehow on remove?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about removing the `class` on the click and adding it back on the success retrieval?

```
$(".clickMe").click(function() {
    var trID = $(this).closest("tr").attr("id");
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: { 
            contID: trID
        },
        success: function(data){
            $("#"+trID).remove();
            $("#contTbl tr:even").removeClass("altBgr");  
            $("#contTbl tr:even").addClass("altBgr");
        }
    });
});
```

**Edited**: as per my own comment

> You can try putting both the removeClass() and addClass() in the
>   success: and see if that eliminates the flicker

Comment: You can try putting both the removeClass() and addClass() in the success: and see if that eliminates the flicker @santa

Comment: Bingo. Moved both in success function and flicker is gone.

Answer (score 1):

You could place it in a function and call it again (don't forget to remove the classes before adding them again).

Or use CSS to do your colouring with [`:nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/%3anth-child)...

```
tr:nth-child(even) td { 
    background: #f03;
}
```

...keep in mind < IE 9 won't play nice.

Comment: I tried putting it in a function but for some reason, all rows become the same color when a row is removed...

Comment: I had so much hope for IE9 :(

Comment: @santa: IE9 will do it, less than IE9 won't.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function like this:

```
function set_odd_even(){
    alert($("table tr"));
    $.each($("table tr"), function(index, value){
        alert(value);
        $(value).removeClass('even');
        if(index % 2){
            $(value).addClass('even');
        }
    });
}
```

And then call it in your success event:

```
success: function(data){
    $("#"+trID).remove();
    set_odd_even();
}
```

Comment: Wow, that seems like a lot of code for such a benign functionality... I'm sure it works well though! Thanks.